# Hibernate and Stored Procedure w/o Parameters and Return

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, stored-procedures

I've been looking for ways to map in Hibernate my Stored Procedure that don't have both parameters and return variable, unfortunately I only found the how-to's with Stored Procedures that has parameters and/or return variable.

What do you guys recommend in working around on it?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch18.html#sp_query):

> The stored procedure/function must return a resultset as the first
>   out-parameter to be able to work with Hibernate.

But you can always call the stored procedure directly, by-passing Hibernate limitations:

```
session.doWork(new Work() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{ call my_stored_procedure() }");
        callableStatement.executeQuery();
    }
});
```